# XML Doctype Definition

Tags: xml, doctype

This is my first attempt at XML. I read a lot about it before writing this, but I'm a little bit confused on if I am doing the DOCTYPE definitions correctly? Can someone take a look and let me know?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE quiz [
<!ELEMENT quiz (items)>
<!ELEMENT items (item)>
<!ELEMENT item (question,answer)>
<!ELEMENT question (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT answer (#PCDATA)>
]>
<quiz>
  <items>
    <item>
      <question>What is the name of the movie with jedis?</question>
      <answer value="0">Star Trek</answer>
      <answer value="0">E.T.</answer>
      <answer value="1">Star Wars</answer>
      <answer value="0">Titanic</answer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <question>What is my favorite color?</question>
      <answer value="0">Blue</answer>
      <answer value="1">Purple</answer>
      <answer value="0">Green</answer>
      <answer value="0">Pink</answer>
    </item>
    <item>
      <question>What comes after 2?</question>
      <answer value="1">3</answer>
      <answer value="0">1</answer>
      <answer value="0">4</answer>
      <answer value="0">11</answer>
    </item>
  </items>
</quiz>
```

Also, this is obviously a quiz app. Is there a standard way of making the XML inaccessible so that people can't read the answers from pulling it up in a browser? It will be used with AJAX and PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your answer has to do with your DOCTYPE declaration question, but you do need corrections. You need to add some occurrence indicators and an ATTLIST declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE quiz [
<!ELEMENT quiz (items)>
<!ELEMENT items (item+)>
<!ELEMENT item (question,answer+)>
<!ELEMENT question (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT answer (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST answer 
          value CDATA #REQUIRED> 
]>
```

Comment: :-) I thought it might have been.

Comment: Can you recommend any sites to read more about this type of thing? It's really fascinating but I barely know what to Google for!

Comment: Not really. You can take a look at the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-doctype A good XML book would probably help too.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem.

Paste the second line under the xml opening tag.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet href="no.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>

Make a second file named no.xsl and paste something like this:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
    encoding="iso-8859-1"
    indent="yes"
    method="html"
    version="4.01"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
        <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://WHEREVER YOU WANT TO REDIRECT TO">
      </head>
      <body>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course, you don't have to redirect. That just works best in my case.

Comment: While that might prevent the casual user from seeing the XML as it is displayed in the browser, it won't completely hide the information. All they would have to do is "view source" and the raw XML is displayed.

Comment: Interesting! Sorry, I deleted that on you. I'm not very good with this site yet.

Comment: <Files *.xml>
    Deny From All
</Files>
in htaccess?